# Want a good Tutorial for NSInputStream and NSoutputStream

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Does anyone know where I can find a good tutorial about `NSInputStream` and `NSOutputStream`?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/ReadingInputStreams.html

Answer (score 1):

I have found this one as best :)

For NSInputStream :

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html

For NSOutputStream:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSOutputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: thanks anoop but i have used this...and i want something executable code..

Comment: thats just the class ref for NSInput- and NSOutput-Stream. Here is a link to the actual programming guides provided by apple, they are a lot more helpful to get started with:https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Streams.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a game or an application that should connect to server via socket connection and would like to have some real-world examples, this tutorials from Ray Wenderlich and the team might help you.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4456/how-to-make-a-multiplayer-iphone-game-hosted-on-your-own-server

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4471/how-to-make-a-multiplayer-iphone-game-hosted-on-your-own-server-part-2

Comment: they suggested server programming using python , do you have any idea with PHP ??